# GAMMA vs simple linear regression write up APA style

Tags: r, regression, gamma-distribution

I have been taught in my course to write up my normal linear regression results in this format:
“F(1, 97) = 0.07, p = 0.794, Adjusted R2 = 0.01, f2 = 0.01, accounting for 1% of the variance.”

I am wondering how to write up the simple linear gamma regression output in APA format as it does not provide a df (I.e. (F1, 97)” or an adjusted R squared value.